# Is the double-checked lock idiom safe if the initializer code is split between methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I found this code in some open source code that I've been seeing erratic behavior with, which shall renamed unnamed (names have been changed).   I'm pretty sure it's not thread safe, because the resource is missing the volatile keyword.

Also, I am not sure if the idiom works when split the way it is.  [Josh Bloch claims](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/bloch-effective-08-qa-140880.html) the idiom is fragile and should be implemented as documented otherwise it may not work (though he doesn't explain why).  Plus the double-write does not smell write.

Besides the lack of volatile here, how might this code fail in a multithreaded app?

```
private Resource defaultResource = null;

public Resource getSession() {
    if (defaultResource == null) {
        defaultResource = initializeResource();
    }
    return defaultResource;
}

private synchronized Resource initializeResource() {
    if (defaultResource == null) {
        defaultResource = getResourceBuilder().build();
    }
    return defaultResource;
}
```

edit:  Using Java 8

Comment: For **what** *version* of Java? Anyway, I think it's safe. The compiler can't reorder it and the method is `synchronized`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not safe -- but because of the usual double-checked lock problems, not because of the second method call. Specifically, a second thread could see a non-null `defaultResource` and thus access it without ever having seen the synchronized method, and thus not establishing a happens-before edge with its invocation on the first thread; but that would be exactly the same problem of it were an inlined `synchronized (this)` block.

You're right about the volatile, too. If the field were volatile, then reading it would establish a happens-before with its previous write.

Methods have no bearing on the Java memory model (JMM) — unless they're synchronized, in which case their effect is exactly the same as a `synchronized` block. Rather than thinking of methods, I would encourage you to think of specific *actions*: what actions establish a happens-before edge? In the code you provided, the only actions that can provide a happens-before edge are the acquisition of `this`'s monitor (by entering the synchronized method) after the previous release of that same monitor (by another thread exiting that method). So then you have to ask: is there any way we can read a non-null `defaultResource` without having gone through those actions? The answer there is yes: in fact, it's done any time `defaultResource` is non-null at the beginning of `getSession`. Thus, each one of those accesses is a data race.

Comment: In fact, the method could easily be inlined by the JIT and so all you really have is a `synchronized (this) {}` wrapper which back to the original problem.